# Why aren't C++ compilers optimizing more string constructions away in pass-by-value scenarios?

Tags: c++, compiler-optimization, stdstring, copy-elision, stdmove

<sub>(This question is inspired by [Nicolai Josuttis' CppCon 2017 talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PNRju6_yn3o).)</sub>

Consider the following source file (for an object, not a complete program):

```
#include <string>

class C {
    std::string s_;
public:
    C(std::string s) : s_(s) { };
    void bar();
};

void foo() {
    std::string hello { "The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog" };
    C c { hello };
    c.bar();
}
```

And its [compilation result on GodBolt](https://godbolt.org/g/WRXSCd).

Even with the `-O2` (and even with `-O3`) it seems a string constructor is called three times. Specifically, `s` is constructed, used only to construct `s_`, then destructed. My questions:

- Is the compiler allowed to simply construct `s_` from the arguments to the ctor, not constructing `s` at all?
- If not, is the compiler allowed to move-construct `s_` from `s`, seeing how the latter is unused?
- If any of the previous answers is "yes" - why aren't gcc and clang doing so?
- If `s` is properly constructed, can't the compiler avoid the construction of `hello`, seeing how it has no other use? Or at least move from it?

Comment: You need `-std=c++14` with clang 5.0.

Comment: Try to formulate a fool-proof pseudo-algorithm that does the optimization you want. It's harder than you might expect. If you ever get done express it in C++, extensively test it with hopefully all edge cases and then send clang a pull-request.

Comment: @nwp: I didn't say "this optimization should happen, why isn't it?" ... I don't know the answer.

Comment: I remember them only recently specifying that memory allocation is not a side-effect, so depending on the standard you use compilers might not be allowed to do that optimization. I forgot which version changed that.

Comment: @nwp memory allocation is not observable behavior of the abstract machine if all uses of that memory are traced (and you can do link time analysis to ensure that nobody injected a non-default operator new on you)?

Comment: @nwp: Your first sentence seems to contradict your second statement. If it _were_ a recognized side-effect then maybe it's necessary to keep it.

Comment: @einpoklum Well, those contradictions are a good reason I put them as comments and not as answers. I feel that even though at least one statement is at least partially incorrect they are still points worth looking into.

Answer (score 9):

Under as-if, I'm certain most of what you ask for could be done, *assuming* you go to link time and you make `bar` empty and never override new anywhere.

But then, under as-if, your program is an empty program, it has no observable effects.

The compiler is not permitted to move construct `s_` from `s` under the rules of the abstract machine.  If you want it to be move constructed, `std::move` it.

The situations where an lvalue can be treated as an rvalue are limited and specific and involve `return x;` statements.  This is not a `return x;` statement.

So your code *must* copy `s` into `s_`.  Quite possibly it should also generate a warning as a quality of implementation issue.

The compiler is not permitted to elide `s` into `s_`.  There have been some [c++20](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b20) proposals to permit much more aggressive elision rules.

But as of right now, elision is only permitted under as-if, with prvalues, or with `return x;` statements.  As-if elimination is really, really hard to prove with something as complex as allocation, most compilers don't try.  And it isn't possible at object file generation, because someone could replace the global allocator.

Imagine a global allocator override that prints out how many allocations are done.  Then those "never used" objects are used in that they should print out the allocations they do.

Or a global allocator that calls `exit` after 2 allocations.  The abtract machine resulting should never call `bar()`; if we eliminate your extra objects, the program doesn't behave as the standard mandates.

Comment: Under as-if, the object file is not empty, since you don't know what `C::bar()` does.

Comment: @einpoklum Sure; but neither is allocation, because you could have overridden the global new allocator.   Anyhow, edited to reflect that.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Aren't the global new and delete part of the standard library? They aren't overridden in the source... and are you saying that the pathology of overriding global new is what prevents the optimizations here?

Comment: @einpoklum The possibility that someone overrides global new/delete means that calls to new/delete cannot be eliminated under "as-if" until link time.  Elision can eliminate the creation of objects and does not rely on "as-if", which is the usual way that this optimization can occur.  Your cases are not (as of [tag:C++17]) valid elision cases.